# Only static memebrs can be accessed in initializers

Tags: flutter, dart

I am passing a variable to other screen and I want to use that as value for `videoplayer` but I am getting this Error `Only static members can be accessed in initializes` I try to find the solution but everywhere I found to replace final with static keyword than it will work but id did not work for me but do for others. I am using that title by widget.title but error shown on the other hand I used same in `Text(widget.title,),` and it is working good here but not here final `videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.title);`

```
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';


class ChewieListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  ChewieListItem({this.title});
  bool looping;
  @override
  _ChewieListItemState createState() => _ChewieListItemState();
}

class _ChewieListItemState extends State<ChewieListItem> {
  List data =[];
  final videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.title);
//  static videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.title);
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      autoInitialize: true,
      looping: widget.looping,
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            errorMessage,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  void fetchData() async {
    final response = await http
        .get('http://salterz.com/gtv_json/link.json');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        data = json.decode(response.body);

//         Final=dataleft +data +dataright;

      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
    return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Chewie(
              controller: _chewieController,
            ),
            Text(widget.title,),
          ],
        );
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    // IMPORTANT to dispose of all the used resources
    videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Appraoch 1: Pass it while constructing State

During object construction/initilizing variables its just a Dart class, it doesn't know anything about widget etc.
To address your issue just pass `title` to State like

```
class ChewieListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  ChewieListItem({this.title});
  bool looping;
  @override
  _ChewieListItemState createState() => _ChewieListItemState(title: title);
}
class _ChewieListItemState extends State<ChewieListItem> {
  final String title;   
  final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
_ChewieListItemState({this.title}): videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(title);
...
}
```

#### Appraoch 2: Initilize videoPlayerController in `initState`

```
Or initialize `VideoPlayerController` in `initState` and destory in `dispose`.

class _ChewieListItemState extends State<ChewieListItem> {
  List data =[];
  VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
  ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.title);
    ...
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    videoPlayerController.dispose();
    ...
  }
  ..
}
```

This way you can have better cleanup than first option. I prefer second option.

Comment: I did already try second approach but I face other error if I put it according to second approach I  face issue on videoPlayerController.dispose();

Comment: undefined name  videoPlayerController. in this line videoPlayerController.dispose();

Comment: So `videoPlayerController` might not have cleanup method (which isn't mandatory). Then just ignore that. You don't need to do it.

Comment: than how can I dispose my `videoPlayerController`. and can you clarify what does ignore mean here?

Comment: If something (videoPayerController) needs cleanup, usually they provide `dispose` method. If `dispose` isn't provided either it means, it doesn't need cleanup or they missed it. You have to choices 1. Implement `dispose` on `VideoPlayerController` if you feel necessary. 2. Remove line `videoPlayerController.dispose();` from `dispose` method as you can't do it (This is what I mean by ignore it)

Comment: Thank you very much Chenna stay blessed. approach 1 work for me really really thanks.  I will be very thank full if you share why it was so "To address your issue just pass title to State like" what was my mistake.

Comment: Check https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour (section *Invoking a non-default superclass constructor*) to know why initilizer list can't use member (`widget`) of super/parent class (`State`). Because its not yet constructed.

Answer (score 1):

According to second approach you will not able to dispose video player. So First approach will work fine.

Comment: Yeah I do apply second approach It did not work but first approach works fine. Thanks for your reply Danish